# How to set View position that looks same on different density devices

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to set view positions that looks same on all type of density devices 
`lddpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xxhdpi`

My UI simple contains `TextView` and `ImageView` but it looks at different place in different density devices... though I have set view positions according to screen size using Display matrix..

Comment: Can you add your layout.xml please? Otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

use nine patch image is goood option for  your  problem.

Comment: does he only mention image ? He said view which includes Text View and Imageviews